# What's the best way for a process to know when another one is terminated?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pipe, signals

I am coding in C and I wanted to know if there is a way another process can know if another one terminated via threads or named pipes, or would it be better with signals? What is the best way do to that?

**More info:** I am not working with sockets. Only fifos and threads. I have one process that is the server. Another the client. And when the server shutdown I wanted the client to know it and shutdown too. Thanks

Some parts are in portuguese. I hope you can understand the context :/

---

## *util.h*

```
#define FIFO_SERV "cli.txt"
typedef struct{
    char u[10], pass[10];
    char op;
    int pid;
    int acesso;
   //int FIM;
 } PEDIDO;
```

## *servidor.c* - server file

```
#include "util.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *f_dados;
int fd, fd_resp, i;
char cmd[20], user[10], pwd[10], users[100], str[80];
PEDIDO p;

fd_set conj;
struct timeval tempo;
int ret;


    mkfifo(FIFO_SERV, 0600);
    fd = open(FIFO_SERV, O_RDWR); //vai ler para escrever

    printf("Servidor iniciado...\n");


    f_dados = fopen(argv[1], "w+");
    do{
        FD_ZERO(&conj);
        FD_SET(0 ,&conj);   //ATENCAO AO TECLADO!
        FD_SET(fd, &conj);     //ATENCAO AO FIFO!
        tempo.tv_sec = 1;      //ESPERA 1.5 SEGUNDOS
        tempo.tv_usec = 50000;

        ret = select(fd+1, &conj, NULL, NULL, &tempo);

        if(ret > 0){    //existem dados
            if(FD_ISSET(0, &conj)){         // ... no teclado!

                scanf("%s", cmd);

                if(strcmp(cmd, "user") == 0){
                    f_dados = fopen(argv[1], "a+");
                    if (f_dados == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("NÃO FOI POSSIVEL A ABERTURA DO FICH.\n");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    scanf("%s %s", user, pwd);
                    fprintf(f_dados, "%s %s\n", user, pwd);
                    printf("\t#user adicionado\n");

                    fclose(f_dados);
                }
                else if(strcmp(cmd, "users") == 0){
                    f_dados = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
                    if (f_dados == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("NÃO FOI POSSIVEL A ABERTURA DO FICH.\n");
                        return 1; 
                    }

                    while(fgets(users, 100, f_dados)) {
                        printf(">%s\n", users);
                    }
                }
                else if(strcmp(cmd, "sair") == 0){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("\tComando inválido.\n\n");
                }
            }
            if(FD_ISSET(fd, &conj)){         // ... no fifo!
                i = read(fd, &p, sizeof(p));
                if(i==sizeof(p)){
                    printf("Recebi um pedido...");
                    printf("Pedido: %s %s {%d}\n", p.u, p.pass, p.pid);

                    autenticacao(f_dados, &p);
                    //ENVIAR RESPOSTA...
                    sprintf(str, "cli%d", p.pid);
                    fd_resp = open(str, O_WRONLY);
                    i = write(fd_resp, &p, sizeof(p));
                    close(fd_resp);

                    printf("Enviei a resposta...\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }while(strcmp(cmd, "sair") != 0);

    close(fd);

    fclose(f_dados);

    printf("Vou terminar!\n");

    unlink(FIFO_SERV);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

## *cliente.c* - client file

```
#include "util.h"
    int main(void) { 

        int fd, i, fd_resp, res;
        char str[80]; //buffer para guardar dados
        PEDIDO p;

        if (access(FIFO_SERV, F_OK) != 0){
            printf("O servidor nao esta a correr!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        p.pid = getpid();
        sprintf(str, "cli%d", p.pid);
        mkfifo(str, 0600);

        fd = open(FIFO_SERV, O_WRONLY);
        do{
            //INTERFACE
            printf("\nLogin: ");
            scanf("%s", p.u);
            printf("Password: ");
            scanf("%s", p.pass);

    //        printf("\nPEDIDO: %s - %s\n", p.u, p.pass);
            //INTERFACE... ainda falta

            i = write(fd, &p, sizeof(p));
            printf("\nPedido enviado...");

            //RECEBE RESPOSTA...
            fd_resp = open(str, O_RDONLY);
            i = read(fd_resp, &p, sizeof(p));
            close(fd_resp);

            printf("Recebi a resposta... {%d}\n", p.acesso);
            if(p.acesso == 0){
                printf("\n\t[Não autenticado.]\n");
            }
            else if(p.acesso == 1){
                printf("\n\t[Autenticado.]\n");
            }

        }while(!p.acesso && strcmp(p.u, ".") != 0);


        close(fd);

        unlink(str);
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: How are the processes related?  Is one a parent of the other?  Is there some ancestral relationship?  Or are they unrelated?  Does the process that needs to know have the same privileges as the one that dies (same EUID)?  There are probably other questions that are relevant too.

Comment: I have one process that is the server. Another the client. And when the server shutdown I wanted the client to know it and shut down too. I hope I made myself clear. I am very rusty yet. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: I am not using sockets... I am using fifos and threads.

Comment: You did not answer any of the questions that @JonathanLeffler asked you.

Comment: OK; how does the client connect to the server?  Is there a single client using a well-known FIFO name?  Are there threads running in the client, the server, or both?  When the server shuts down, do all its threads terminate?  If so, all the FIFOs that are open (however many they are) will be closed.  Any client waiting to read will get EOF; any client trying to write will get SIGPIPE or the write will fail.  So at one level, it doesn't much matter how the clients connect via FIFOs; when the server dies, the clients will all be told by the next communication operation failing.

Comment: If you need a more prompt notification — so the client shuts down even if it is not trying to talk to the server at the time — then you need to think about having the client tell the server what its PID is, so that just before it dies, the server can send an appropriate signal (SIGTERM or SIGHUP spring to mind) to the client.  That assumes that the server has permission to send signals to the client — I asked about it before but it hasn't been addressed.  There's a reason why we like to see an MCVE ([MCVE]); it saves us from trying to pull hen's teeth to get the information we need to help.

Comment: I added some code... Hope it can help. Sorry for the bothering. And thanks one more time for the help.

Comment: This is a project for university. And the teacher is asking in one topic that when the server process shutdowns it needs to warn the client process and shut it down too. 
In another topic he says that the server process should end when the SIGUSR1 signal is received.

Comment: I was thinking on something like: when the server receives the signal it will be able to send a message or something to the client. Thus the client would read it and shutdown too.

Comment: Why not just implement a heart beat using a pipe (for example)

Comment: What do you mean by using a heart beat?

Comment: Braces in your `servidor.c` are unbalanced.